# Problems about get_variable() and variable_scope()

Tags: tensorflow

I retrained the inception-V3 model according to the image_retrain example with one extra conv and pool layers on the top of the original bottleneck layer. The two layers are initialized with `get_variable()` function
in a `variable_scope()` and after training the graph and parameters are stored in a `.pb` file.
But when I read the just trained `.pb` file for test and want to retrieve the variables in the two layers, with `variable_scope()` and `get_variable(,reuse=true)`, exception are raised about

> Variable weights/W does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?'

**Environment Information -**

***Operating System***: Ubuntu 14.04

***Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN***:
cuda 8.0
cudnn 5.1

> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened
>   CUDA library libcublas.so locally
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened
>   CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened
>   CUDA library libcufft.so locally
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened
>   CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
>
> I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened
>   CUDA library libcurand.so locally
>
> 0.12.0-rc0

I initialize the two extra layers as:

```
  with tf.variable_scope('CAM_unit'):
      CAM_conv = new_conv_layer(bottleneck_input,   [3,3,BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE,BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE], 'CAM_CONV')
      CAM_pool = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.relu(CAM_conv), [1,2], name='CAM_AVG_POOL')
  with tf.variable_scope('weights'):
      layer_weights = tf.get_variable('W', 
                                      shape = [BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE, class_count], 
                                      initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.01))
```

And access the weights/W variables as:

```
with tf.variable_scope('weights', reuse=True):
        label_w = tf.gather(tf.transpose(tf.get_variable('W')), label)
```

I tried to set `reuse=None`, but the error is:

> Shape of a new variable (weights/W) must be fully defined, but instead was

I doubt about the `.pb` file in which the model converged with a very high accuracy, because when I retrain again with this output `.pb` file, the accuracy is very low like an untrained one. But I imported the model, the new added layers are there as expected, just inaccessible with `get_variable()`
I import the `.pb` file and search for the target layers with code:

```
ops = [op.name for op in graph.get_operations() if 'weights/' in op.name]
    pprint.pprint(ops)
```

and find the weights/W variables are available:

```
[u'weights/W', u'weights/W/read']
```

Comment: Do you want reuse=True on the first weights var scope and not the second?

Comment: I set reuse=True when i wanna retrieve the var in the trained model, when i trained the model reuse = None

Comment: I found a strange phenomenon. even though i save the graph file and its weights with graph_util.convert_variable_to_tensor(), the accuracy is still low when i retrain with the .pb file again. Is this a bug? this happened even on the official image_retrain example.